# Slack move to Channel upon Modal Submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm using a Slash Command to trigger a new Modal view and the app is listening only to `view_submission` events.

The modal is collecting the user response from 2 `static_select` elements.

Having the channel_id and team_id values how is it possible to redirect the users to the selected channel immediately upon clicking the Submit button?

Meanwhile, I'm returning a button that has a deep link URL value: `slack://channel?team=${team_id}&id=${channel_id}`

But that's a poor user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Slack's Dev Support, there's currently no way to direct a user to a different channel upon submission completion. Returning a button with a deep link is the best way to handle it as of right now. Alternatively,  another option is posting a message and linking them directly to the channel after the submission using the below:

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#linking-channels